# Filter an array by schoolType

Tags: php, html, api

I am calling an API that returns me an array of schools. I want to filter that array by schooltype and display the school type in the drop down. When I do that I get null values.

```
function getSchools() {
  $path = $GLOBALS['f1Settings']['baseUrl'] . '/v1/People/Schools.json';
  $r = $_SESSION['f1Obj']->fetchGetJson($path);
  $schoolarray = array();
  //loop through results to build array of schools
  if ($r) {
    foreach($r['schools']['school'] as $school) {
      array_push($schoolarray,array('name'=>$school['name'],'id'=>$school['@id']));
    }
  }
  array_multisort($schoolarray,SORT_ASC);
  echo(json_encode($schoolarray));
  }
```

HTML that output the array:

```
<label for="school">School:</label>
<select id="school" class="required" name="school">
  <option value="">Select...</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What is the structure of r['schools'] ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If r['schools']['school'] is already an array, all you need to do is assign it to the array outside of your loop. This will sort them by name:

```
 if ($r) {
foreach($r['schools']['school'] as $school) {
  $schoolarray[ $school['name'] ] = $school;
 }
}
```

The problem with your output is that you need to use something unique, like school id, as the value given and you can loop through the school name as display. Not sure where your HTML is and how you serve it, but once you have your schoolarray array then you can do something like this:

```
<select id="school" class="required" name="school">
<?php
foreach ( $schoolarray as $name => $data )
{
   echo "<option value=\"data['@id']\">$name</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

You may have to edit it to the proper array indexes

Comment: It displayed Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /nfs/c05/h03/mnt/18844/domains/integrations.gethope.net/html/111/templates.php on line 105

Comment: Which foreach loop is that? If it is the top one, I used the same parameters you used. If its the bottom one, then $school is not as described or the indices are different. you may have to change

Comment: Almost there! the error is fixed. not it show a huge array of the same school name that is not a (School Type = university) unless am missing something. 
I want to be able to set it to get School Type university which should only get all the universities

Comment: Nice, well keep playing with it. If it helps, I usually do one of these to see the structure of what I am working with:
echo "<pre>";
var_dump( $r['schools'] );
die("End");
then I can see the structure and the depth I need to work with. Keep at it